# syntax of a srv file

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi
I am trying to write a service that uses the data that the drc robot is publishing on the imu topic. if i write rostopic type /imu | rosmsg show ,
I get -

```
std_msgs/Header header
  uint32 seq
  time stamp
  string frame_id
geometry_msgs/Quaternion orientation
  float64 x
  float64 y
  float64 z
  float64 w
float64[9] orientation_covariance
geometry_msgs/Vector3 angular_velocity
  float64 x
  float64 y
  float64 z
float64[9] angular_velocity_covariance
geometry_msgs/Vector3 linear_acceleration
  float64 x
  float64 y
  float64 z
float64[9] linear_acceleration_covariance
```

I tried this-

```
sensor_msgs/Imu imu
---
float64 ubx
float64 mby
```

the package compiled but the server isn't working.
the files are
Server

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

#####################################################################################



import roslib; 
roslib.load_manifest('imu')

from imu.srv import *
from imu.msg import *
import rospy, math , sys
from std_msgs.msg import Float64
from geometry_msgs.msg import Vector3
from sensor_msgs.msg import *
class Namespace2: pass
ns = Namespace2()
ns.old_time_nsec=0.0
ns.old_time_sec=0.0

def imu_controller(req):
    res= ImuAngResponse()
    x_vel=req.imu.angular_velocity.x
    y_vel=req.imu.angular_velocity.y
    z_vel=req.imu.angular_velocity.z
    
    ns.new_time_nsec=req.header.stamp.nsecs
    ns.new_time_sec=req.header.stamp.secs
    new_time=ns.new_time_sec+ns.new_time_nsec*10^-9
    old_time=ns.old_time_sec+ns.old_time_nsec*10^-9
    dt= new_time-old_time
    res.ubx=x_vel*dt
    res.mby=y_vel*dt
    ns.old_time_nsec=ns.new_time_nsec
    ns.old_time_sec=ns.new_time_sec

    
    return res



def imu_controller_server():
    rospy.init_node('imu_controller_server')
    s = rospy.Service('imu_controller', ImuAng, imu_controller)

    
    rospy.loginfo("imu_controller server ready") 
    rospy.spin()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    imu_controller_server()
```

Caller

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

#####################################################################################



import roslib; 
roslib.load_manifest('imu')


from imu.srv import *
from imu.msg import *
import rospy, math , sys 
from std_msgs.msg import Float64
from geometry_msgs.msg import Vector3
from sensor_msgs.msg import *
class Nasmpace1: pass
ns = Nasmpace1()
ns.ImuAng = ImuAngResponse()
imu_controller =  rospy.ServiceProxy('imu_controller', ImuAng)

def imu_control(msg):
   ns.ImuAng=imu_controller(msg)
   ns.back_ubx.publish(ns.ImuAng.ubx)
   ns.back_mby.publish(ns.ImuAng.mby)
   
    



def imu_call():

    rospy.init_node('imu_call')
    rospy.wait_for_service('imu_controller')


    
    ns.back_ubx = rospy.Publisher('/back_ubx_position_controller/command', Float64)
    ns.back_mby = rospy.Publisher('/back_mby_position_controller/command', Float64)
    

    rospy.loginfo( "imu_call node is ready" )
    

    sub=rospy.Subscriber("imu", Imu, imu_control)

    rospy.spin()

if __name__ == '__main__':
     imu_call()
```

the srv file is ImuAng.srv

```
sensor_msgs/Imu imu
---
float64 ubx
float64 mby
```

the error I am getting is

```
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1357222067.922667] [4099.311000] Error processing request: 'ImuAngRequest' object has no attribute 'header'
None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/impl/tcpros_service.py", line 615, in _handle_request
    response = convert_return_to_response(self.handler(request), self.response_class)
  File "/home/nachum/ros/imu/scripts/imu_fix_server.py", line 27, in imu_controller
    ns.new_time_nsec=req.header.stamp.nsecs
AttributeError: 'ImuAngRequest' object has no attribute 'header'
```

what is the right syntax?( I only need the time and angular velocity)

Thanks

Nachum

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51374/syntax-of-a-srv-file/) by [Nachum](https://answers.ros.org/users/2980/nachum/) on ROS Answers with karma: 208 on 2013-01-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

O.K found the problem
It WORKS
instead of

```
ns.new_time_nsec=req.header.stamp.nsecs
ns.new_time_sec=req.header.stamp.secs
```

should be

```
  ns.new_time_nsec=req.imu.header.stamp.nsecs
  ns.new_time_sec=req.imu.header.stamp.secs
```

---

Originally posted by [Nachum](https://answers.ros.org/users/2980/nachum/) with karma: 208 on 2013-01-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1